# Getting exception while executing query in interbase XE7

Tags: interbase, interbase-2009

I have migrate Borland interbase 7 to embarcadero interbase XE7 database. I have taken backup file *.ibk using IBConsole and restored  into interbase XE7 and successfully restored the database on interbase XE7 database but when i tried to execute simple query on IBconsole Interactive sql window, it got the following error message but when tried to different table it execute query successfully.

**SQL**

```
 select * from inventor;
```

**Error Message :**

```
Error at line 1
invalid request BLR at offset 128
function F_BLOBSIZE is not defined
module name or entrypoint could not be found
SQL - select * from inventor
```

I am new for interbase database,so please help why we getting above error message and solution.

Regard's
Sameek

Answer (score 0):

You did not move the UDF dll file(s)

Comment: While perhaps correct, expand on your answer. The poster admits to being new to InterBase, so even if they see the wisdom of what you suggest, probably won't know how to implement it.